# Does time move backwards in Special Relativity

Tags: time

Does time ever go backwards in Special Relativity?

Regarding things like hypersurfaces of simultaneity.

I gather it does not.

Am I overtinterpreting coordinates.

Does time only go forwards? Under normal circumstances anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, do a coordinate transform $t=-T$ and then you rather trivially have time going backwards. When people ask this question that is usually not what they have in mind.

Usually what they have in mind is some coordinate system where, for some fixed values of the spatial coordinates we have that $d\tau/dt$ changes sign, where $\tau$ is proper time and $t$ is coordinate time.

This is not possible. Coordinates are, by definition, required to be a one-to-one map between events in spacetime and points in $\mathbb{R}^4$. If $d\tau/dt$ changes sign then there is a minimum or maximum at the moment when $d\tau/dt=0$. Events on either side of that moment will necessarily share the same $t$ coordinate. And since the spatial coordinates are fixed that means that distinct events will share the same coordinates. That would violate the one-to-one requirement and preclude such coordinates, by definition.

Often this is discussed in terms of the Andromeda paradox. Unfortunately, the usual pop-sci presentation presents this as some amazing truth of relativity. It is, in fact, a simple and rather unimportant mathematical mistake. Time coordinates cannot go back and forth in Andromeda as you pace back and forth here.

Comment: I'm a terrible mathematician is the answer here time doesn't go backwards

Comment: @Simon01_Pringles see the last paragraph. I was writing it while you posted your comment

Comment: Is this the generally accepted stance. Also thank you!

Comment: Yes. It is the only accepted rigorous stance. Pop-sci authors, of course, are not rigorous so they say whatever they think will sell best. Usually with an eye towards “wow” and “that’s weird” reactions from their audience. Regardless of what the rigorous science would say

Comment: So, regardless of interpretation, time doesn't go backwards of forwards for you when I walk away from / approach you

Comment: Yes, it doesn't go backwards for me and it also does not go backwards for you regardless of either of our motion and regardless of whose perspective we are using

Comment: Is this interpretation contrary to that of block time. Or are these ideas completely compatible?

Comment: @Simon01_Pringles comments are intended only to improve the answer, not to have a back and forth discussion. If you would like a discussion format rather than a Q&A format please go to physicsforums.com instead (I am Dale there too). This site is just for questions and answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144626/discussion-between-simon01-pringles-and-dale).